# How to find WiFi password of all available networks on Chromebook crosh?

Tags: chromebook, google-chrome-os

I have a wifi password I need to find, but how can I do something where I can find the WiFi password for all available networks?

Comment: The only WiFi passwords the OS has are the ones from networks you connected successfully in the past. If that is what you're looking for then it's possible but not easy, same as with Android. You need Dev mode and the process is easily searchable in Google. I guess you didn't make any effort whatsoever? This comes in any Google search: https://www.howtogeek.com/824544/how-to-find-your-wi-fi-password-on-a-chromebook/

Comment: Right now it sounds like you're asking for help cracking wireless network passwords. Do you perhaps mean you wish to retrieve the passwords for networks that you have already connected to in the past? If so, please edit your question to make this clear.

Answer (score 0):

Easiest way would be to open up crosh and type the following (*Enter* = press enter key):

1. Shell

*Enter*

2. sudo su

*Enter*

3. cd home/root

*Enter*

4. ls

*Enter*

A code will then pop-up, copy this and

5. type cd and paste the code

*Enter*

6. Type: more shill/shill.profile

*Enter*

Search for the line that says "Password=rot47", copy whatever is after this as this is the encrypted password

7. Type: echo randomtexthere | tr '!-~' 'P-~!-O'

- Where randomtexthere is replaced with what you copied from step 6

*Enter*

This should do it. Very long winded way of finding the password but it's the only way I know.

Comment: Ah yes, fair enough. have edited for it to specifically for cosh. Thanks for pointing out.